# Does there exist a general purpose external cooling fan designed for the Lenovo Yoga 2 Pro?

Tags: laptop, cooling

The Lenovo Yoga 2 Pro has a rather unique placement of its internal cooling fan:

The fan is *not* located on the bottom of the machine under the keyboard like most laptops (which most external cooling fans are designed for).

Instead, the internal cooling fan is located at very edge of the laptop where the lid is.

So to use my Yoga 2 Pro with the average cooling fan, I have to put my laptop in the *middle* of the fan, which is very near unusable unless I use an external mouse and keyboard because the laptop would be tilting precariously on the fan.

Does anybody know if there exists a general purpose external cooling fan designed for the Lenovo Yoga 2 Pro, given its particular choice of internal fan placement?